# How to efficiently decode JPEG from Base64?

Tags: android, base64, jpeg

In my android app I capture an image from the camera, compress it to jpeg, send it to the server and save it on hdd. There it takes 48,9kb (e.g.). I send it back in a Base64-String and decode it on the Android side like this:

```
byte[] img;
img = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(img);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 3;

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
return bmp;
```

Values bigger than 3 for

```
options.inSampleSize
```

will make the image look ugly. But if i now look at the size of

```
bmp
```

it is 156kb. Why does the size increase? How can I decode it, so that it keeps its original size and doesnt look ugly (too hard downsampling)?